# SQL Query to XML?

Tags: sql, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have one SQL Query on my C# project with MVC3, that builds a menu structure.
This works but I can not embed my ASPxMenu into the project because for some reason is not compatible with Master page.

Can i convert that Query to XML?

If it will be an XML file, than it`s possible to attach to Html.Devexpress().Menu with .BindToXML

Comment: can you post sql query  that you want to convert into xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking whether you can convert the result of an SQL query to XML and bind to that or do you actually want to bind to the text of an SQL query as XML?  Posting some code would be helpful to visualizing your intent.

Comment: Yes i`m asking that, whether i can convert the SQL result to XML and the obtained XML then bind to the ASPxMenu.